# Neo4j APOC Write operations are not allowed for user 'neo4j' with FULL restricted to READ

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

On my Neo4j 3.3.3 Community Edition I use `apoc-3.3.0.2-all.jar` APOC plugin and I have installed the following APOC trigger:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add('HAS_VALUE_ON_INDEX', 'UNWIND {createdRelationships} AS r MATCH (d:Decision)-[r:HAS_VALUE_ON]->(ch:Characteristic) 
CALL apoc.index.addRelationship(r, keys(r)) RETURN count(*)', {phase:'after'})
```

Trigger is successfully installed, I verified it with `CALL apoc.trigger.list()` command.

Right now when I try to use Manual Index on Relationship Properties with the following query:

```
CALL apoc.index.relationships('HAS_VALUE_ON','value:10000.32') YIELD rel, start AS d, end AS ch RETURN rel;
```

The Neo4j returns the following error:

```
Write operations are not allowed for user 'neo4j' with FULL restricted to READ.
```

How to remove this restriction?

**UPDATED**

I noticed that after the first test run  - everything is working fine. The logic fails on the second consequent test run with the following query:

```
CALL apoc.index.relationships('HAS_VALUE_ON','value:10000.32') YIELD rel, start AS d, end AS ch RETURN d;
```

with the following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.PermissionDeniedDataAccessException: Error executing Cypher; Code: Neo.ClientError.Security.Forbidden; Description: Write operations are not allowed for user 'neo4j' with roles [admin] restricted to READ.; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher; Code: Neo.ClientError.Security.Forbidden; Description: Write operations are not allowed for user 'neo4j' with roles [admin] restricted to READ.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SessionFactoryUtils.convertOgmAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:164)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.SessionBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor.translateExceptionIfPossible(SessionBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor.java:71)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy156.findFromIndexByDecisionOnCharacteristic(Unknown Source)
    at com.decisionwanted.domain.DecisionCharacteristicIT.testRelationshipValueTriggerAndIndex(DecisionCharacteristicIT.java:510)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher; Code: Neo.ClientError.Security.Forbidden; Description: Write operations are not allowed for user 'neo4j' with roles [admin] restricted to READ.
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.response.BoltResponse.next(BoltResponse.java:48)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.map(GraphEntityMapper.java:87)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.lambda$executeAndMap$1(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:124)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.doInTransaction(Neo4jSession.java:544)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.doInTransaction(Neo4jSession.java:523)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.executeAndMap(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:120)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.query(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:90)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.query(Neo4jSession.java:414)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator$SharedSessionInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedSessionCreator.java:131)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.query(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.execute(GraphQueryExecution.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.doExecute(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.AbstractGraphRepositoryQuery.execute(AbstractGraphRepositoryQuery.java:51)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Write operations are not allowed for user 'neo4j' with roles [admin] restricted to READ.
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketResponseHandler.handleFailureMessage(SocketResponseHandler.java:76)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.PackStreamMessageFormatV1$Reader.unpackFailureMessage(PackStreamMessageFormatV1.java:470)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.PackStreamMessageFormatV1$Reader.read(PackStreamMessageFormatV1.java:431)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketClient.receiveOne(SocketClient.java:196)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketConnection.receiveOne(SocketConnection.java:217)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.ConcurrencyGuardingConnection.receiveOne(ConcurrencyGuardingConnection.java:165)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.PooledSocketConnection.receiveOne(PooledSocketConnection.java:183)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalStatementResult.receiveOne(InternalStatementResult.java:335)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalStatementResult.tryFetchNext(InternalStatementResult.java:325)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalStatementResult.hasNext(InternalStatementResult.java:193)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.response.GraphModelResponse.fetchNext(GraphModelResponse.java:36)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.response.GraphModelResponse.fetchNext(GraphModelResponse.java:26)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.response.BoltResponse.next(BoltResponse.java:45)
    ... 64 more
```

Comment: Is this server or embedded?

Comment: Server Community Edition. Also, right now trying Enterprise Edition

Comment: what's you apoc specific config settings in `neo4j.conf`?

Comment: I have updated my question with APOC specific properties

Comment: what roles does your user neo4j have? admin?

Comment: Yes, I use 'neo4j' user with 'admin' role

Comment: I'm getting the same error message after running following query: `call apoc.cypher.run("create (n:Test) return n",{}) yield value`

The exact error message is `Neo.ClientError.Security.Forbidden: Write operations are not allowed for user 'neo4j' with roles [admin] restricted to READ.` on Neo4j 3.4.0